# How to detect FULL height of window in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dhtml

How can I detect the full height of a screen in javascript? This includes the Y-Overflow. So far, I haven't been able to find a script for it.

Comment: Your question title says "window", your question says "screen", but you imply "document" or possibly "document if the longest element was unconstrained". Which do you mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
document.body.offsetHeight
```

or

```
$('body').height();
```

if you're using jQuery

Comment: How can I detect, from this, whether the window is scrolled to the very bottom?

Comment: use [this code](http://thought-bytes.blogspot.com/2007/02/ie-and-firefox-scroll-offsets.html)

Comment: I made my own: (It doesn't work, can you see anything wrong with it?)  http://dabbler.org/home/asdf/scrolling/test.html

Comment: you should make a new question for this

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function pageWidth() {return window.innerWidth != null? window.innerWidth: document.body != null? document.body.clientWidth:null;}
function pageHeight() {return window.innerHeight != null? window.innerHeight: document.body != null? document.body.clientHeight:null;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the height of the page content? If so, [this](http://www.irt.org/script/1400.htm) should do the job.